# Redirecting standard output

Tags: c#, process, output, io-redirection

I have a C# application `A` which calls another C# application `B`, which calls multiple instances of application `C`.

I would like to redirect the output of application C to the output of application A.

I already have a working redirection of the output of application `B` into the output of application `A`.

Now, from within application `B`'s code, I'm redirecting every process's output, and I'm printing the redirected output to the console. Unfortunately, for some reason, nothing is printed.

(I'm currently testing it without using application `A` - I'm only running application `B`).

Here is the code:

```
private void runSingleFile (string execFile, string commandArgs)
{
      Process processToRun = new Process();
      processToRun .StartInfo.FileName = execFile;
      processToRun .StartInfo.Arguments = commandArgs;
      processToRun .StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      processToRun .StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
      processToRun .OutputDataReceived += outputRedirection;
      processToRun.Start();
      Console.WriteLine("");
      Thread.Sleep(100);  
      processToRun.BeginOutputReadLine();
}

private void outputRedirection(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
      try
      {
           if (outLine.Data != null)
              Console.WriteLine(outLine.Data);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
          return;
      }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Some applications write to StandardError instead of StandardOutput, have you tried redirecting your StandardError as well?

Comment: I know for sure that application `C` write to the StandardOutput, I wrote it..Anyway, I tried that now - still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted works.  Given test program

```
// ConsoleApplication2.exe
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test1...");
    Console.WriteLine("Test2...");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    Console.WriteLine("Test3...");
}
```

called as :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    runSingleFile("ConsoleApplication2.exe", "");
    runSingleFile("ConsoleApplication2.exe", "");
    runSingleFile("ConsoleApplication2.exe", "");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

produces output :

[image]

Clearly something else is not working in another part of your code (Something you have not shown us).

The most likely explanation, if application `C` is working correctly, is that application `B` is terminating before all instances of `C` have completed.  You may have to add some code that makes `B` wait for all instances of `C` to return.

Note that :

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     runSingleFile("ConsoleApplication2.exe", "");
     runSingleFile("ConsoleApplication2.exe", "");
     runSingleFile("ConsoleApplication2.exe", "");
     //Console.ReadLine();   // ** Don't wait!
 }
```

completes immediately and fails to return some or all of the data (especially if you remove the `Sleep` call in `runSingleFile`.

Consider :

```
 static long processCount = 0;               //ADD

 static void runSingleFile(string execFile, string commandArgs)
 {
    Interlocked.Increment(ref processCount);  //ADD
    Process processToRun = new Process();
    processToRun.StartInfo.FileName = execFile;
    processToRun.StartInfo.Arguments = commandArgs;
    processToRun.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processToRun.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processToRun.OutputDataReceived += outputRedirection;
    processToRun.EnableRaisingEvents = true;  //ADD
    processToRun.Exited += processExited;     //ADD
    processToRun.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("");
    processToRun.BeginOutputReadLine();
 }

 static void processExited(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Interlocked.Decrement(ref processCount);
 }
```

with

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     runSingleFile("ConsoleApplication2.exe", "");
     runSingleFile("ConsoleApplication2.exe", "");
     runSingleFile("ConsoleApplication2.exe", "");
     while (Interlocked.Read(ref processCount) > 0)
     {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
     }
 }
```

The above then makes application `B` wait until all spawned processes have returned.  The example is simplistic and obviously can be improved upon, but it demonstrates the problem, I think, and offers a method for the solution.

You might be tempted to use something more elegant like [`WaitHandle.WaitAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6.aspx), but this does introduce the problem that josh noted where your output events may not fire until after the process terminates - the process handle will signal that it has terminated but its posted messages may still be in the queue.  Waiting on the `Exited` event tidies up that race condition since that event will always be the last message in the queue (AFAIK).

Also, note the use of `Interlocked` functions here - `Console.WriteLine` is threadsafe but other variable access is not.  Since there is no synchronization context in a console application the events raised by spawned processes are handled by threads in the threadpool (not the main thread of the console application).  This introduces all of the issues associated with multithreading which must be managed appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The .net `Process` object doesn't make it easy for one to "do the right thing" with respect to correctly handling the IO.

These pages list some of the concerns that need to be dealt with:

- MSDN's [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) page
- Raymond's blog [Be careful when redirecting both a process's stdin and stdout to pipes...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/07/07/10183884.aspx)
- C# test.net's [How to use System.Diagnostics.Process correctly](http://csharptest.net/321/how-to-use-systemdiagnosticsprocess-correctly/)

From your code sample, here are some of the items that you will want to look at:

1. You will want to capture both stderr and stdin (the latter should be immediately closed if not used).
2. You also need to be aware that you can still receive events on your `outputRedirection` callback *after* the child process has exited.